# Are robotic, riderless street bikes common now?

Tags: self-driving

I just saw what looked like a normal bicycle drive around the a block a few times without a rider. There was a clear plastic box with some electronics, a motor on the back wheel and something connected to the handlebars (presumably some servo mechanism), and a person briskly walking next to it with some gizmo in their hand, but at a few paces distant and not touching it.

It could turn a fairly sharp corner at speed, with a radius of perhaps 3 meters.

There were some packs that could be weights and/or batteries near the seat as well.

Is this *unusual* or particularly challenging or a just-recently-solved engineering challenge, or is this well known and oft-repeated feat?

Comment: I need help with tagging, thanks!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzTxuI37ZF0

Comment: @RoryAlsop excellent, yes that's it!.. except a street bike at a fast walking pace. I think with the low speed and higher center of gravity it gets more difficult, which is why I felt it was so remarkable, which is why I thought I'd ask here. Thanks for the link!